# Why on the ATLAS Higgs discovery paper there are uncertanties on the expected cross section upper limits but not on the observed upper limits?

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, statistics, large-hadron-collider

I was reading the ATLAS paper on the Higgs discovery and a question came to my mind. In the plot I attached, there are uncertainty bands on the background only hypothesis upper limits, and not on the observed upper limit.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why that happens?

Here is the link to the paper if anyone wants to read it: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.7214.pdf

Comment: I think the bands are a combined effect of all the errors. Have you looked at the definition of CLs in reference 123? In the abstract "I argue that the so-called CLs technique for setting limits is appropriate for determining exclusion intervals" , so it is not as simple as you imagine.

Comment: What does it mean to have an uncertainty on a limit? A limit quoted to a partiuclar confidence level is already a statement of uncertainty. Your bog-standard error bar can be thought of as the interval between upper and a lower limits at 68% CL.